# haskell record parameter or alternative

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am using [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0) for parsing a https://jsonlines.org/ files. Those files are dumps of Elastic Search indexes so the outermost structure is the same in all JSON objects. If I understood right, record syntax do not allow parameter like in the `Document` record below, right? What would be the alternative?

One possible solution would be to use the [JSON AST](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:3) to read the JSON innermost objects and parse them latter, is it possible? How?

```hs
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Either
import Data.List
import GHC.Generics


data Suggestion =
  Suggestion { ... }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Synset =
  Synset { ...}
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Document a =
  Document a
    { _index :: String
    , _type :: String
    , _id :: String
    , _score :: Int
    , _source :: a
    }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

readJ :: L.ByteString -> Either String Document
readJ s = eitherDecode s :: Either String Document

readJL :: FilePath -> IO [Either String Document]
readJL path = do
  content <- L.readFile path
  return (map readJ $ L.split 10 content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, record syntax does allow type parameters, you just shouldn't repeat them after the constructor name:

```hs
data Document a =
  Document
    { _index :: String
    , _type :: String
    , _id :: String
    , _score :: Int
    , _source :: a
    }
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have one readJ per (Document a) instantiation. But I think I can do better yet.